# Best Approach for Bookmark Drill through in Power BI

Tags: sql-server-2008, powerbi, dax

I have a single session date(Day) chosen on the Dashboard home landing page ( page 1) via a dropdown date slicer. The chosen date is a selected date measure defined as:

`SelectedDate = cALCULATE(max('Date'[DayTextLong]),FILTER('Date',SELECTEDVALUE('DateSelector'[DateId],MAX('DateSelector'[DateId])) = 'Date'[DateId]))`

DateSelector table is a standalone disconnected date table that is a cutdown list of dates for dropdown to select a day for slicer. There is a connected DATE table in this data model.

On a scorecard on the Dashboard home landing page ( Page 1), for a daily amounts on sessions I have a bookmark( as cant drill through on scorecards), to a details table and on that page 2, I want to show the details of which customers. This is from a table that contains a request date and I need to filter the table by the selecteddate measure . How can I show a summarised table visual on Page 2 that filters from the Selected Date measure chose on Page 1?

I was trying to create a measure (Request Date Boo) that would set a measure to 1 or 0 for the relevant records to show from Session Requests table , which is just Session Name, Customer Name and request date , and then put a visual filter on for page 2 to say where Request Date Boo=1.  This fails with an error around single value not being found as it telling me I need to aggregrate the request date.

I want to do this properly and wondered what is the normal way of showing a visual on page 2 of a Report , where you want to use a date and apply a filter to another table in the data model using that date.

Hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Can you post several rows of sample data cooked for this example? And desired results, please as well.

Comment: Yes sometimes less is more. It is very hard to understand this question. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: A possible answer to your question, from what I understood, it is to use a hidden slicer in the Page 2 which is synched with the Slicer in Page 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-slicers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understood, you have a filter on page 1, that must be kept when you navigate to page 2.
I've got three options:

1. Put the same date filter slicer on page 2 and allow it to sync with the others. In this way, when you navigate between pages that share synced slicers the filters will be kept. (this was also suggested by a comment)
2. Use the drillthrough functionality ([docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-drillthrough)). This is a bit more complicated and does not create a "standard" page but it allows you to navigate to a detail page, based on a set of configured fields, when you navigate to this page you can also keep all the filters that were set before reaching this page. (This is a bit complicated to explain, the best thing you can do is to try it and see if it suits your needs)
3. Use What If parameters [(docs here)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-what-if). I've never used for something like that, but if you can use them to choose a date you may use them to solve your problem.

All considered, probably the first solution is the easiest and most common solution for this kind of problem